# How to change color of Triangle figure using drawRect on Swift

Tags: swift, drawrect

I have made triangle view, called UpTriangleView. It is used in order to show vote. When they are tapped, I want to change their color. I wanna `UIColor.grayColor().setStroke()` from instance, however I have no idea how to do it. Please tell me how to do it, if you know. Thank you for your kindeness.

```
class UpTriangleView: UIView {

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    // Get Height and Width
    let layerHeight = self.layer.frame.height
    let layerWidth = self.layer.frame.width

    // Create Path
    let line = UIBezierPath()

    // Draw Points
    line.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, layerHeight))
    line.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(layerWidth, layerHeight))
    line.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(layerWidth/2, 0))
    line.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, layerHeight))
    line.closePath()

    // Apply Color
    UIColor.grayColor().setStroke()
    UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
    line.lineWidth = 3.0
    line.fill()
    line.stroke()

    // Mask to Path
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = line.CGPath
    self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
  }
} 


class QATableViewCell : UITableViewCell{   
  @IBOutlet weak var upTriangleView: UpTriangleView!
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a property to your `UpTriangleView` that is the color you want to draw it.  Implement `didSet` and call `setNeedsDisplay()` if the color is set:

```
class UpTriangleView: UIView {

    var color = UIColor.gray {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear

        // Get Height and Width
        let layerHeight = self.layer.bounds.height
        let layerWidth = self.layer.bounds.width

        // Create Path
        let line = UIBezierPath()

        // Draw Points
        line.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: layerHeight))
        line.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: layerWidth, y: layerHeight))
        line.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: layerWidth/2, y: 0))
        line.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: layerHeight))
        line.close()

        // Apply Color
        color.setStroke()
        color.setFill()
        line.lineWidth = 3.0
        line.fill()
        line.stroke()

        // Mask to Path
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = line.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
}
```

Now, demo it in a Playground (see picture below for results):

```
let utv = UpTriangleView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
utv.color = .yellow  // now triangle is yellow
utv.color = .red     // now triangle is red
```

`setNeedsDisplay` will tell iOS your view needs redrawing, and `drawRect` will be called again using the newly set color.

[image: Picture of triangle in Playground]

Comment: Thank you vacawama...it worked like a charm... really helpful.